# How long left in current session/cookie for WordPress

Tags: wordpress, session, cookies

How would I display the current amount of time left of the cookie/session for a logged in user of WordPress? So for example if the cookie timeout is 24 hours and the user has been logged in for 2 hours then the output would be 22 hours.

Answer (score 1):

Wordpress (2.9) stores the log in expiry date (along with other log in details) in a cookie prefixed 'wordpress_logged_in_'. So, you should be able to do something like the below to display the time until expiry.

```
foreach ($_COOKIE as $key => $cookie) {
    if (strpos($key, 'wordpress_logged_in_') === 0) {
        $cookie_array = explode('|', $cookie);
        $expiry_time = $cookie_array[1];
        echo human_time_diff(mktime(), $expiry_time);
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have Chrome, you can get the [Edit This Cookie](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/edit-this-cookie/fngmhnnpilhplaeedifhccceomclgfbg) extension and view or edit cookies without writing code. I believe Firefox has a similar extension.